# Get reference to specific selector on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<select>` that is being dynamically created. In order to bind a change event to it, I am using the following code:

```
$(document).on('change', $('select[name^="time_types"]'), function() {
    // do something
}
```

I need to get a reference to this specific `<select>` element in order to append some text to a sibling.

For example:

```
$(document).on('change', $('select[name^="time_types"]'), function() {
    $('select[name^="time_types"]').siblings('.mileageInfo').append('Some text.');
}
```

Obviously this will append "Some text." to the end of every single `<select>` element on the page with a name beginning with "time_types", which is not what I want.

How can I get a reference to the specific `<select>` that is passed to the $(document).on() function above so that I can append text only to that element?

Comment: In jQuery any event handler will have it's scope set to the element which raised the event, as such you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element. Also note that `select` elements can only contain `option` or `optgroup` elements, so appending plain text will cause some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get a reference to the specific  that is passed to
>   the $(document).on() function above so that I can append text only to
>   that element?

simply replace

```
$('select[name^="time_types"]').siblings('.mileageInfo').append('Some text.');
```

with

```
$(this).siblings('.mileageInfo').append('Some text.');
```

`$(this)` will refer to the current select box.

By the way, [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method doesn't take a jquery element. Instead, it takes the selector string.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name^="time_types"]', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.mileageInfo').append('Some text.');
}
```

Comment: $(this) seems to be getting a reference to the document and not the select box.

My mistake. I'm actually appending to a sibling of the select, not the select itself. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Here is a quick jsfiddle I threw together: [https://jsfiddle.net/xmcpj6p7/](https://jsfiddle.net/xmcpj6p7/). I am not receiving the alert I'm expecting.

Comment: @markusmayhem check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/xmcpj6p7/2/

Comment: Ah, I see what I was doing wrong. Silly mistake. Thank you so much!